# What function has derivative $\log(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the derivative of a function $f(x)$: $f'(x) = \log(x)$, where $\log(x)$ is the natural logarithm. What's the original function $f(x)$ and what is that calculation called in English?

Comment: This is called "integrating $\log(x)$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$[x \ln x -x\ ] + C$ is what you're looking for, it's called the anti-derivative of $\log x$

Comment: ...plus a constant....:)

Comment: obviously... =)

Answer (score 11):

*Hint* : integrate by parts.  $du = dx$, $v=\log{x}$.

> $$\int \log{x} \, dx = x \log{x} - \int x \frac{d}{dx} (\log{x}) = x \log{x} - x + C$$

Comment: Ah, _integration_ it's called. But I'm a newbie, so I cannot follow the rest of your answer. Can you explain?

Comment: [Integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), there are some examples

Answer (score 4):

$x \log x - x$ try differentiating this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to think about it if you haven't been introduced to integration.

$ \begin{aligned} \displaystyle  \log{x}  = (\log{x}+1)-1  = (x)'\log{x}+x(\log{x})'-1+0 = (x\log{x})'-(x)'+(\mathcal{C})' = (x\log{x}-x+\mathcal{C})' \end{aligned}  $

Where $\mathcal{C}$ is any constant. Therefore your function is $f(x) = x\log{x}-x+\mathcal{C}$.